# Get Value of field of unmatched ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs

```
            <div>
              <input  type="text" name="rate" ng-model="rate" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/"/>
            </div>
                <span class="text-warning control-label">
                    {{rate}}
            </span>
```

rate displays when a valid value is typed in the text field and shows up as NaN when an invalid value is typed. The ng-pattern accepts +numbers upto 2 decimals  , i'd like the rate to show up if i type 123.4567 or -383

Answer (score 0):

figured out the solution. I used form.rate.$viewValue to get the value of the input text box.